# How to position grid elements

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation, grid-layout

I'm having problem where, for [example](http://imgur.com/phVOmwl), I have a title placed on the page in a certain place using i.e. `top: 150px;`
However, once I start reducing my window size it cuts off my background. I realized that using tags like `top/bottom/left/right` or `margin-top` causes this to happen since it wants to stay at that certain place and doesn't reduce the size along with the window.

I've tried using `background-size: cover;` in my `body` and various positions in my `#title` but still couldn't fix this problem.

CSS

```
html {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#gradient {    
    background: #00BFFF;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right bottom, #086A87, #00BFFF);
    background: linear-gradient(to right bottom, #086A87, #00BFFF);
    border-radius: 2px;
    /*    background-size:cover;*/
    background-size:100% 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

#title {
    font-size: 60px;
    color: #FF8000;
    /*    margin-top: 150px;*/
    /*    position: fixed;*/
    /*    position: relative;*/
    top: 150px;
}
```

HTML

```
<html>
 <body id="gradient">

<!-- Title -->
 <div class="row ">

    <div id="title" class="small-16 large-12 large-centered text-center columns">Example</div>

  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

What's the best way to position grid elements that eliminates these kind of problems?

I'm having a hard time positioning elements on the page using the grid system.

Thanks!

EDIT: Updated HTML

EDIT 2: If you resize the height to really small you can see my problem. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RNXrMM

Comment: could you post your html also please?

Comment: I'm sorry about that, I thought I did put it. Updated the question with the HTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The core issue here is that you shouldn't be positioning or styling grid elements (with the possible exception of background). Place your title element inside the grid, where content belongs, and style it accordingly.

```
<div class="gradient">
    <div class="row header">
        <div class="small-16 large-12 large-centered text-center columns">
          <div id="title">Example</div>
        </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

**[Demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vEoLQj)**

Note that I've moved the background to a div element rather than the body, and I've used a class, which is preferable for CSS because it makes it more reusable and robust.

Comment: What would a good way to move the `Example` or any other grid elements to a certain place? For example, I want to move it maybe around 3/4 lower. If I use anything like `top` or `margin-top` it will messes up the whole background again.

Just started learning the grid system so I'm having a little bit of trouble with positioning.

Comment: As you can see in the demo I provided, I've added a top margin to the title element that doesn't impact the grid. I've also just added a min-height to the div with the background so it covers the entire page.

Comment: Thanks, just wondering if you can help me with one more problem I'm having. The background works fine now, however, if I have the title at `margin-top: 250;` it would appear normally when the window is full size but when I reduce the window size somewhat smaller then the `Example` title would always be at the bottom. Is there a way I can have the title position based on the window size?

Comment: Google "media queries". It's pretty simple to set CSS for specific screen widths. You'll want to align your media queries with the breakpoints ZF is using to prevent weirdness.

Answer (score 0):

On the matter of the gradient 'disappearing' on resize, if you change

```
html {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
```

to

```
html {
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
```

it should resolve that. Also allows you to use

```
 #title {margin-top: 150px;
```

without any cutoff - though, if you want your design to be responsive (and it sounds a little like you do) - I'd recommend using ems or % for your margins to making it a little more consistent.

you can see the [fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/adk4bnh5/)

Comment: I'm still having that problem even when I changed it to `min-height: 100%;`. There was no difference at all.

Comment: Can you create a fiddle with your full CSS and html? Or a link to a live example? It works on my fiddle so there may be something else in your code. Just to confirm your problem is only with the background cutting off, not with the actual positioning of your #title element?

Comment: The problem I'm having is the background is cutting off or I believe the problem I'm having is that the position of my element goes beyond the background size. I don't think it's my background cutting off, but could it be? 
If you resize the height to really small you can see my problem.
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RNXrMM

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `min-width:1000px`
You can set pixels according to your need

The CSS code for this :-

```
html {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    min-width: 1000px;
}

#gradient {    
    background: #00BFFF;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right bottom, #086A87, #00BFFF);
    background: linear-gradient(to right bottom, #086A87, #00BFFF);
    border-radius: 2px;
    /*    background-size:cover;*/
    background-size:100% 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

#title {
    font-size: 60px;
    color: #FF8000;
    /*    margin-top: 150px;*/
    /*    position: fixed;*/
    /*    position: relative;*/
    top: 150px;
}
```